# Multihomed Ubuntu 14 using "internally optimized routing"

Tags: linux, networking, routing, nic

I have an Ubuntu 14 server which is multihomed with two identical 1Gb network cards.

The physical subnet routing is handled by another department. As such, when I want to add a new machine (or NIC) to the network, I use a web interface into the DNS/DHCP service - giving it the MAC address of the computer/NIC, which is then automagically associated with a DNS resolution name and IP address (the IP is assigned to the card using DHCP).

When I inherited this server, it had one NIC enabled and one NIC disabled. The MAC addresses for BOTH NICs were in the DNS service, so I re-enabled the second NIC.

I.e. In the DNS service...

```
(ETH0) A0:A1:A2:A3:A4:A5 = 123.123.123.10, Servername1
(ETH1) B0:B1:B2:B3:B4:B5 = 123.123.123.11, Servername1a
```

**However, ALL traffic sent to the second NIC (ETH1), ends up on the first NIC (ETH0) - even when IP is used - regardless of the packet type (ICMP, SCP, etc.)**

For example, if I `root@123.123.123.100# scp ./bigfile.tar 123.123.123.11:/tmp` and then run `pktstat -i eth0 -nt` on Servername1, I see ...

```
interface: eth0
bps

   bps    % desc
 51.2k   35% tcp 123.123.123.100:754 <-> 123.123.123.10:2049
```

***Notice that it's reporting the bandwidth as coming into 123.123.123.10*** and NOT 123.123.123.11. There's no doubt this traffic is the `bigfile.tar`

It's also important to note that the tools on the server (like tcpdump) show that ***NO packets whatsoever EVER pass across ETH1***.

The admin in control of the routing told me "*your problem is a linux kernel internally optimized routing*" issue. I'm not sure if he's referring to the kernel on MY linux server, or on the router.

**Nonetheless, I can't find anything on the web using, specifically, the term *"internally optimized routing"*. Can someone offer some insight as to what he's referring?**